# Duplicate entries in webix datatable when changing state of ui-router in angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, firebase, webix

I am having problems with webix datatable.

I am boulding an application with AngularJs and ui-router with webix integration.

When i refresh my site, everything is O.K. But when i redirect to another view the datatable load duplicate entries.

I am using webix and firebase extensions.

I think this is somehow related to angular so i please for an answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have some problem with data IDs. Webix widgets may render data twice if .load was called twice and each time data with different ( or missed IDs ) was loaded.

If you have a .load somewhere in your code, try to prepend it with .clearAll call

```
grid.clearAll();//delete an existing data
grid.load("some");//load new data
```